# Getting a refresh token from google api

Tags: google-calendar-api, token, access-token

I've looked through other posts and they're either unanswered ([Stopped getting refresh token from google's API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537792/stopped-getting-refresh-token-from-googles-api)) or no longer correct it seems.

I am trying to get a new refresh token from the google api, I have access_type = 'offline' and approval_prompt = 'force' but the response I'm getting back does not contain a refresh token.  The other posts I have looked through says that having those two parameters should return me a refresh token.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I was thinking perhaps I could revoke the auth and have the user re-auth to get a fresh refresh_token.  Would this work/is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out, instead of using approval_prompt=force you can use:

```
{       
        ...
        access_type='offline',
        prompt='select_account consent'
}
```

to force a new approval screen and get a new refresh token.